# Navigators and tags

Tags: html, css

I must to create a navigator is it possible to write a code as this ? Is it correct ? I have read that I will should to use tags

```
  <div class="topnav">
    <a class="active" href="index.php">HOME</a>
    <a href="#">ABOUT US</a>
    <a href="#">INVESTEMENT PLAN</a>
    <a href="#">NEWS</a>
    <a href="#">FAQS</a>
    <a href="#">RULES</a>
    <a href="#">CONTACT US</a>
  </div>
```

But How to adapt in my CSS ??

```
/* The navbar */
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: baseline;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-spacing: 0px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 13.333px;
  display: block;
}

/* Navbar links */

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;

}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: You can style your elements however you want. Note that there is HTML5 elements for that `<nav>`

Comment: what do want to achieve? it seems like your code have already create a navbar, it's up to you to choose which tag you want to use in your html but there are some tags that have purpose of creating navbar and that give some mean to your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The nav tag is in the HTML like this:

```
<nav class="topnav">
    <a class="active" href="index.php">HOME</a>
    <a href="#">ABOUT US</a>
    <a href="#">INVESTEMENT PLAN</a>
    <a href="#">NEWS</a>
    <a href="#">FAQS</a>
    <a href="#">RULES</a>
    <a href="#">CONTACT US</a>
  </nav>
```

You are looking for this, I guess.